Porque sale este error de React?
No entiendo porque me sale este error. Estoy exportando todos los elementos de la misma manera pero no me funciona y em salta este error en consola. Todo este error me sale en app.jsx. Estuve importando otras cosas de la misma manera y no me sale error. Importante aclarar que en El visual studio code no sale ningún error, el error aparece únicamente en la consola de Chrome.
El componente publicidad:
import React from 'react'
import '../styles.css'

const Publicidad = () => {
    return (
        <div className='publicidad'>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae 
              numquam explicabo perferendis nulla dicta sit culpa vel at sequi 
              nesciunt ea doloremque eligendi ipsa, maxime ut est repellat adipisci 
              asperiores?
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Publicidad;

ERROR: SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/components/Publicidad.jsx?t=1718983231343' does not provide an export named 'Publicidad' (at App.jsx:4:10)

App.jsx:4:10: import { Publicidad }  from './components/Publicidad'

Otros importes que hice sin errores:
import { Encabezado } from './components/Encabezado'
import { Carousel } from './components/Carousel'



Hola, cuando exportas un componente con  default como en export default Publicidad; la forma de importarlo es import Publicidad from './components/Publicidad'  sin las llaves {}. Te recomiendo revisar este link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Hice lo que me decis pero continua sin mostrarme el componente de publicidad

Sigue saliendo el mismo error ?

Ya descubri que es lo que pasa, el componente publicidad sale dentro del carousel. El componente carousel lo esta tapando. Como puedo hacer para que aparezca debajo del carousel??

Ponle un z-index con un valor  grande en el css del componente que quieres se muestre al frente, pero aclaro que como tu error (el de la pregunta) ya no se presenta y es diferente a tu error de estilos ya no deberiamos seguir haciendo comentarios  aca, a menos que actualices la pregunta para no hacer ruido.

Lo que estás haciendo es desestructurar para obtener los módulos de la carpeta Components
La forma correcta de importar tus módulos sería:
import Carousel from './components/Carousel'
import Publicidad from './components/Publicidad'

Sin los curly brackets entre los nombres de los componentes
